# Legends not showing matplotlib.patches <matplotlib.patches.Patch object at 0x*****>

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

So, I have been working around with a dataset to visualize it. I'm new to seaborn and using matplotlib in general. However, I am not sure what exactly is causing the legends to not show the right colors.

*I wanted to plot the # of cyclists observed at 4 bridges all in their own column in df.

```
df = data
#sns.barplot(x='Precipitation', y='Total', data=data, palette='summer')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18, 7))
Date = df['Date']
bridges = df[['Brooklyn Bridge', 'Manhattan Bridge','Williamsburg Bridge','Queensboro Bridge']]
c = sns.pointplot(data=df, x=Date.dt.month_name(), y='Brooklyn Bridge', color="b",
                  label="Brooklyn Bridge")
d = sns.pointplot(data=df, x=Date.dt.month_name(), y='Manhattan Bridge', color="r",
                  label="Manhattan Bridge")
r = sns.pointplot(data=df, x=Date.dt.month_name(), y='Williamsburg Bridge', color="g",
                  label="Williamsburg Bridge")
w = sns.pointplot(data=df, x=Date.dt.month_name(), y='Queensboro Bridge', color="black",
                  label="Queensboro Bridge")
b_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='b', label='Brooklyn Bridge')
r_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='r', label='Manhattan Bridge')
g_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='r', label='Williamsburg Bridge')
black_patch = Patch.Patch(color='#000000', label='Queensboro Bridge')
ax.set_title('Number of cyclists by Bridge', fontsize=22, y=1.015)
ax.set_xlabel('month-day-year', labelpad=16)
ax.set_ylabel('# of people', labelpad=16)
ax.set(yscale="log")
t = plt.xticks(rotation=45)
ax.legend(labels=[b_patch, r_patch, g_patch, black_patch])
```

However, the legend looks like this:
[image]

Not sure how exactly I could fix it - any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try `ax.legend(handles=[b_patch, r_patch, g_patch, black_patch])`?

Comment: `ax.legend(handles=ax.lines[::len(df)+1], labels=['Brooklyn Bridge', 'Manhattan Bridge', 'Williamsburg Bridge', 'Queensboro Bridge'])`. Note that you need to add `ax=ax` to `sns.pointplot(data=df, x=Date.dt.month_name(), y='Brooklyn Bridge', color="b", ax=ax)`.

Answer (score 0):

Sample graphs from the official website created a customized answer. The `ax.legend()` is specified with 'handles='.

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

ax = sns.pointplot(x="day", y="tip", data=tips, ci=68, color='g', label='Label A')
ax = sns.pointplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, ci=68, color='r', label='Label B')

b_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='g', label='Label A')
r_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='r', label='Label B')

ax.legend(handles=[b_patch, r_patch])
```

[image]